# div-box flickering when flaw with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make `hover image-zoom` effect in basic HTML gallery with CSS-3 styles. The every 5th box is always flickering on mouse over.  Can anyone help point out where the bug code is... Thank you in advance.

#### CSS:

```css
body {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
#container {
    width:738px;
    height:600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#ex2 img{
    height: 88px;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
}

#ex2 img:hover {
    height: 189px;
    width: 258px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="containerEx2">
        <div id="ex2">
            <img src="images2/dm1_large.jpg"/>
            <img src="images2/dm2_large.jpg"/>
            <img src="images2/dm3_large.jpg"/>
            <img src="images2/dm4_large.jpg"/>
            <img src="images2/dm5_large.jpg"/>
            <img src="images2/dm6_large.jpg"/>
            <img src="images2/dm7_large.jpg"/>
            <img src="images2/dm1_large.jpg"/>
            <img src="images2/dm2_large.jpg"/>
            <img src="images2/dm3_large.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you mean jumping down a line once one of the images in the row gets big enough?

Comment: you might want to add to your post that this is happening on firefox (use the edit link)...

Comment: not only firefox, it's happening in Chrome too

Comment: @KarimAG I use Chrome 34 on OSX 10.9 and it's not an issue there, it is an issue on firefox 30 though...

Comment: >webeno >>>yes jumping down and the last image stucks& flickering

Comment: I may have a solution for you... checkout my answer... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you split the images into 2 rows, all the other answers provided cause some kind of trouble with flickering in firefox. You will still need to increase the width of the container, but the 6th image will not jump up a line if you have 2 rows. I also turned the `id`'s grouping your images into `classes` for ease of use in your css:

#### HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="containerEx2">
        <div class="ex2"> <!-- `id` has become a `class` -->
            <img src="images2/dm1_large.jpg" />
            <img src="images2/dm2_large.jpg" />
            <img src="images2/dm3_large.jpg" />
            <img src="images2/dm4_large.jpg" />
            <img src="images2/dm5_large.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="ex2"> <!-- `id` has become a `class` -->
            <img src="images2/dm6_large.jpg" />
            <img src="images2/dm7_large.jpg" />
            <img src="images2/dm1_large.jpg" />
            <img src="images2/dm2_large.jpg" />
            <img src="images2/dm3_large.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```css
body {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
#container {
    width:800px; /* ensuring 5th image remains on the 1st line */
    height:600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.ex2 img { /* changed #ex2 (hash) to .ex2 (dot) */
    height: 88px;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
}
.ex2 img:hover { /* changed #ex2 (hash) to .ex2 (dot) */
    height: 189px;
    width: 258px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

#### Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N3nLq/2/

Comment: thank you very much. your solution is the most useful! it works accurate in Firefox.  (PS/ i tried to avoid splitting into rows for future adding images from the file listing without the additional div wrapping.) thank you for nice code anyhow:-)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lies in the width of your container. Because it has to push out, it cant stay on the same row, thus it will push it down to the next row. Because this is the active element that has to be switched, it will flicker indeed, cause the element has to move out of the boundries of it's suggested box.

I created a JSfiddle and made your container 100 pixels bigger, resulting in it working just fine.

```
    #container {

      width:838px;
        height:600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/895NY/

**EDIT**

As for the flickering part,  I have no clue. I think it's a firefox issue, cause I tested it in Chrome and it doesn't flicker in my browser.

Comment: This is not the OP's problem. There is terrible flickering (in Firefox, at least) when hovering over the 5th images in the row.

Comment: @TylerH I tested it in chrome and it doesn't flicker. Might be specific to firefox?

Comment: What browser do you use? @user3607215

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the width of the container, you need to increase the width of the container on hover, minor changes in CSS:

```
#container {
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
     width:620px;
     height:600px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
#container:hover {
    width:760px;
}
```

And here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KarimAG/ygFfn/1/)**

Comment: if you hover over one of the 2nd line images, it will jump one of them up a line, hovering over that one will produce the flickering again...

Comment: with your new fiddle, i can reproduce some flickering still, and that now on Chrome too... i admit, it's slightly lighter though... play a little bit with the hovers and you'll see... i believe the only good option is to split the rows while still increasing the container width (it's definitely one of the causes)...